# Add custom headers to SonarQube webhook

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube supports webhooks which makes configured API call to an external server after analysis of a project. It also allows custom values to be added in the payload with the pattern `sonar.analysis.*`.

Is it possible to add custom headers(For example Authentication header) in the API request made to the external server.

Answer (score 2):

For the time being it's not possible.

Next version of SonarQube *may* be able to send authentication headers to the external server : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9919

My bad, the issue referenced is just for extracting the credentials from the URL.